# Angular 2 updating an observable

Tags: angular

I'm using the following method in order to create an observable to run API call every 5 seconds and check for new user activities:

```
getLastActivity()
{
    return Observable.interval(5000).startWith(0)
        .switchMap(() => this.http.get('user-activity'))
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

I subscribe it in the component where the activity is shown, which is my sidebar (all pages).

```
let activitySub = this._myService.getLastActivity()
        .subscribe( data => this.activities = data.user_activities);
```

Sometimes the user is making an activity and I want to show the newly added activity in the sidenav instead of waiting 1-5 seconds (observable time).

Adding the action manually with object `push` to the activity objects array is not an option since these actions are inserted server side.

When I tried to run:

`this.getLastActivity.subscribe(() =>{});`

I got an error since I'm already subscribed to this observable.

**My question:** how I can execute the observable API Call even though the time left for the observable next run hasn't passed yet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge 2 observable: the "interval" observable and the "user activity" observable.

```
let intervalOb = Observable.interval(5000).startWith(0);
let useractivityOb = ... // you need to convert user activity to an observable
Observable.merge(intervalOb, useractivityOb)
    .switchMap(() => this.http.get('user-activity'))
    .map(res => res.json());
```

Or you may use a subject:

```
let subject = new Subject();
subject.switchMap(() => this.http.get('user-activity'))
    .map(res => res.json());
Observable.interval(5000).startWith(0).subscribe(subject);
// and now everytime there is a user activity, call subject.next()
```

Comment: I don't get `"// you need to convert user activity to an observable"`. what did you mean by it? and will it reset the "cooldown" of the 5 seconds? (that means if the observable has been executed manually, it will re-count the 5 seconds)

Comment: You can use a subject as in the second part. And no, it will not reset the 5s timer. If you need to reset the timer on every `http.get('user-activity')` let me know. It will be a little more complicated though